# Using gitlab behind router and portforwarding?

Tags: gitlab

My current setup is that I have an Ubuntu VM with gitlab installed (gitlabVM).  Gitlab is running on nginx over port 8888

My router is configured as the following:

External 4322 -> gitlabVM:22
External 8888 -> gitlabVM:8888

If I am at a remote location, how do I connect back to do a git clone?

Ive tried git+ssh://myuseringitlab@routerip:4322/root/repo.git but i get an error that there are no repositories.

the url in gitlab is git@localhost:root/repo.git.

Comment: Have you found the solution, i'm going to make the same confguration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?
`git+ssh://git@routerip:4322/root/repo.git`

You have to provide the `git` user. Your Gitlab user credentials are asked at the next step (if you don't use SSH auth).